# How do I find Property name for xml file of a spring class?

Tags: spring, spring-data

I am working on a spring project and trying to create a bean in spring.xml for spring class. How do I find all the variables/attributes present in that spring class?

For eg:- org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource

As I am following a tutorial link I know that the class/parent class is having the below variables
-driverClassName
-url
-username
-password

But when I checked the doc
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html
I am not getting those details.
So if I want to set values in spring.xml for any class say **X**, how do I know what variables are available in it and how I can find them?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I am not sure this will work every time, but if it is a pojo, and it has a setter, for example setPassword, then there is a property password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to read the documentation.

Google for "DriverManagerDataSource" points us to this documentation:
   https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html

Since we know that a readable property always starts with `get` and have no arguments (except for booleans who often starts with  `is`) we see that the documentation offers absolutly NO property but the [Superclass `AbstractDriverBasedDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.html)

[image]

does offer:

- getCatalog()
- getConnection()
- getConnectionProperties()
- getPassword()
- getSchema()
- getUrl()
- getUsername()
- ...

As you might guess, there are more superclasses that may offer properties.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. But still it is a tedious process to know the property any class.

Comment: @SrinathS You had no fun? I am jumping circles. ;)